# Verify cancel_return parameters

Tags: paypal

When I click the cancel link in PayPal and am redirected to my cancel_url, it is passed the following parameters (some values removed).

```
cmd=_flow&
myAllTextSubmitID=&
miniPager=&
currentSession=&
pageState=login&
currentDispatch=&
email_recovery=false&
password_recovery=false&
login_email=&
login_password=&
private_device_checkbox_flag=on&
SESSION=&
CONTEXT=&
cmd=_flow&
id=&
close_external_flow=false&
external_close_account_payment_flow=payment_flow&
cancel_return=&
auth=&
form_charset=UTF-8&
external_remember_me_read_cookie_ids=&
flow_name=xpt%2FCheckout%2Fwps%2FLogin&
fso=
```

Is there any way to verify that this is a legitimate cancelation similar to how IPN verify works?

Answer (score 0):

None of this looks like PayPal data. It looks like you're passing that stuff to yourself in the cancel URL, or via your original form. In which case you can pass yourself a ticket that only you can generate and verify. There's no need from Paypal's point of view to provide a verification, as no transaction has occurred.